# how to get the current value of a UISlider

Tags: ios, uislider

i need to get the current value of a UISlider and put it into a variable.
my UISlider name is `searchRadiusSlider` and i want that the value will be `%.0f`.

i could display it as a String like that :

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [(UISlider *)sender value]];
```

but for my case, i want simply to get it as numeric :

```
self.searchRadius= //what to put here
```

Thx in advance :)

Comment: do you also want to drop the decimals or just grab the value?

Comment: Hi, i really want to get a value like 10 and not 10.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to drop the decimals just cast to int and this will truncate the decimals.

> self.searchRadius =
>   (int)searchRadiusSlider.value;

If you want to round the decimals like `%.0f` use round() from math.h (Not exactly, `%.0f` uses banker's rounding whereas round() uses half up rounding so 2.5 is rounded to 2 in the former and 3 in the later)

> self.searchRadius =
>   (int)round(searchRadiusSlider.value);

Comment: mmmm, so i have to use round to get values like 20, 30 etc ??

Comment: @malek "i want that the value will be %.0f" then you want to round

Answer (score 2):

self.searchRadius = searchRadiusSlider.value;

Comment: Hi, i really want to get a value like 10 and not 10.0 , what i got is a value as 20.0 but i want 20 too short :))

Comment: Malloc the slider value varies from 0.0 to 1.0 by default.  you can either multiply the result or change the slider's min and max values.  Either way it comes as a float which you can typecast to the desired type.